# Windows 7 Slow bootup after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

my initial machine was Windows 7 x64. then I decided to try Ubuntu 12.04. so as of now Ubuntu 12.04 is installed in another partition and it really boots fast. however when I select Windows 7 as my operating system on the grub selection menu it tooks about 30seconds before it boots to the login screen. Before I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on dual boot windows 7 doesn't boot this long. is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

- Windows 7 was already installed (and working well)
- Installed Ubuntu 13.04 with option to install alongside existing OS

Then, Windows 7 took a long time (2-3 mins) to boot.  Plus, it was very slow, system sounds played distorted, and the touchpad was sluggish.

Unfortunately, I do not have a good solution; I booted with a live Ubuntu USB stick, and ran "OS Uninstaller" to remove the Ubuntu installation on the machine.  Afterwards, Windows 7 runs much better.

I suspect that it has something to do with booting Windows 7 from the GRUB menu instead of through it's own bootloader, but I did not have a chance to investigate.